# Soft Body Baking ridiculously slow

Tags: baking, soft-body

I'm working on a soft body simulation and baking it takes like HOURS for just 5 frames. I got an Intel Core i5 9400F, 1060 6G (I don't think GPU is the problem, I'm just baking physics), 16 GB of ram 2666mhz and a 5000 rmp 1TB hdd. Soft Body object has 211 faces and colliding edges is enabled, is hardware fault or something else? It even happens that the colliding object stucks inside the collision and it's kinda frustrating. Since I need this for work I need to speed it up, it's seriously gonna take months and I can't wait that much time...

Comment: Depends on your other settings…can u provide blend file?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @ArisynILY Go to Blend Exchange and upload it here. Here is the link: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=nEp0SbPk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nEp0SbPk/)

Comment: Ok, so I fexed it up by recalculating normals direction, and disabling edges collision. Thanks for helping guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with:

- Recalculating normals
- Disabilng Edge Collisions
- Unassigning collision physics where there will be no collision with the object